# How to use かなう for desires coming true

Tags: grammar, usage

> 「金持ちさえかなえば、自転車もクツも全部かなうってことだもんね」
>   If only you become rich you can have a bike, shoes, everything. That's for sure.

I'm confused about the grammar of how かなう is used in this sentence. My understanding is that it means "to come true" or "to conform (to)".

If I write 自転車がかなう is that good grammar? it sounds to me like the bike is coming into existence, rather than that I get to own a bike.

I guess I would have written 自転車を持っているのがかなう. Is this wrong? Too wordy?

Maybe Xがかなう translates to "wish relating to X comes true". Can I think of it like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an example of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)). 金持ちがかなう and 自転車がかなう are not good grammar on its own. You usually have to say 金持ちになる(という)願いがかなう and 自転車が欲しいという願いがかなう.

> 金持ち<sub>になるという願い</sub>さえかなえば、自転車<sub>が欲しいという願い</sub>もクツ<sub>が欲しいという願い</sub>も全部かなうってことだもんね。

But this "(になる/が欲しい)という願い" is probably something that was already said in the conversation, and repeating it three times in one sentence is too bothersome. So the speaker omitted this redundant part, knowing they can make themselves understood without saying it.